# Extract data from libreoffice calc chart

Tags: graph, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a graph in Calc but not any data points for that chart. How can I extract a raw data in, say, CSV format or create a spreedsheet? [image: A graph]
Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a simple picture, not a "real" chart, then you'll need a 3rd-party digitizing software; AFAIK there's no built-in feature to digitize plots in LO calc. There are some lists of digitizing tools online, for example http://connectedresearchers.com/graph-digitizer-comparison-16-ways-to-digitize-your-data/ . For a free, online tool, you may check the [WebPlotDigitizer](http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/app/) by Ankit Rohatgi.

If it's in fact a chart, and you're searching for the data, do the following:

1. Double-click on the chart; now, it should have a gray border:

   [image]
2. Right-click inside that gray border to open the context menu; select the last entry "Data ranges":

   [image]
3. The content of the "Data Range" field contains the address of the source data for the chart. The sheet name is followed by a `!` sign and the field range:

   [image]

Comment: Thank You very much for an answer! If I hover with mouse over a curve, I can see a xy-value for each data point. I thought that this values are stored somewhere. How else would one see all the values?

Comment: Ok. I've added some information how to detect the data source of a calc chart

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've found the data!